# Enabling CORS with elasticsearch and docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, cors

I'm trying to enable cors to request my elasticsearch endpoints with search UI, this is the error :

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9200/job_name/_search' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have found multiple solutions but none of them works :

Enabling CORS in the environment of docker-compose :

```
    environment:
      - "http.cors.enabled=true"
      - http.cors.allow-origin="*"
      - "http.cors.allow-headers=X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization"
      - "http.cors.allow-credentials=true"
      ...
```

Enabling CORS in the yml of elasticsearch :

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
```

These 2 solutions don't work and I'm blocked.

Do you have any other solutions?